# SetPixel faster on mouse drag

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm creating a cleaning game but encountered a problem when I fast draw a straight line the line is broken but when I slow draw a straight line it works fine

[image]

Below is my code

```
private void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {

         if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out RaycastHit hit))
         {
             Vector2 textureCoord = hit.textureCoord;

             int pixelX = (int)(textureCoord.x * _templateDirtMask.width);
             int pixelY = (int)(textureCoord.y * _templateDirtMask.height);

             Vector2Int paintPixelPosition = new Vector2Int(pixelX, pixelY);

             int paintPixelDistance = Mathf.Abs(paintPixelPosition.x - lastPaintPixelPosition.x) + Mathf.Abs(paintPixelPosition.y - lastPaintPixelPosition.y);
             int maxPaintDistance = 7;
             if (paintPixelDistance < maxPaintDistance)
             {
                 return;
             }
             lastPaintPixelPosition = paintPixelPosition;

             int pixelXOffset = pixelX - (_brush.width / 2);
             int pixelYOffset = pixelY - (_brush.height / 2);

                 for (int x = 0; x < _brush.width; x++)
                 {
                     for (int y = 0; y < _brush.height; y++) {
                         Color pixelDirt = _brush.GetPixel(x, y);
                         Color pixelDirtMask = _templateDirtMask.GetPixel(pixelXOffset + x, pixelYOffset + y);

                         float removedAmount = pixelDirtMask.g - (pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g);
                         dirtAmount -= removedAmount;

                         _templateDirtMask.SetPixel(
                             pixelXOffset + x, 
                             pixelYOffset + y, 
                             new Color(0, pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g, 0)
                         );
                     }
                 }


             _templateDirtMask.Apply();
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start Paint, and using the pen, try draw circles as fast as you can then look at the result:

[image]

Obviously, you didn't draw such straight lines with such clean direction change.

So, how is Paint able to cope up with such huge delta changes?

> Interpolation

Some pseudo code:

- on mouse down

  - get current mouse position
  - if last mouse position has been set

    - draw all the positions between last to current

      - use Bresenham algorithm for instance
  - save current mouse position to last mouse position

You could/should make your algo aware about pen size, with some simple math you can figure out the necessary step in evaluating points in the interpolation.

And don't use `SetPixel`, keep a copy of the texture pixels with `GetPixels32` that you'll update and then upload it all at once using `SetPixels32`.

Comment: I'll try to study about the Bresenham algorithm